# Set a PDF image file in the tex directory instead of the doc directory in l3build

Tags: dtx, l3build

I have a `xxxlogo.pdf` file, which is a logo image file for users to use with `.cls`. By default, l3build will consider this as a document and place it in the `doc` directory. For this reason, I set some options. At present, the image file can appear in the `tex` directory, but it also exists in the `doc` directory. How can I make the `xxxlogo.pdf` file only appear in the `tex` directory, but not in the `doc` directory?

```lua
module       = "xxxx"
ctanzip      = "xxxx"
tdsroot      = "xelatex"
typesetexe   = "xelatex"
sourcefiles  = {"*.dtx", "*.ins", "xxxlogo.pdf"}
installfiles = {"*.sty", "*.cls", "xxxlogo.pdf"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from [How to set a PDF image file in the tex directory instead of the doc directory in l3build? · Discussion #231 · latex3/l3build](https://github.com/latex3/l3build/discussions/231)

```lua
module       = "xxxx"
ctanzip      = "xxxx"
tdsroot      = "xelatex"
typesetexe   = "xelatex"
tdslocations = {"tex/xelatex/xxxx/xxxlogo.pdf"}
```